# Input format in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am inputting data into my holding database "Premium_DB" in snowflake. But I noticed an omission in the numeric columns. For some reason, snowflake is removing the decimals in the holding database.
For example:
This is my current result

```
(Selected column)       (Input Column)
"GrossPremium"        "Gross_Premium"
    30.52                   30
     4.1                     4
```

Expected Result:

```
(Selected column)       (Input Column)
"GrossPremium"         "Gross_Premium"
    30.52                    30.52  
     4.1                     4.1
```

Is there any way to archive this? Thank you so much for your help.

```
set Reference_Org_Var = 'EXCHANGE_BEN';
set Load_Date_Var = current_date();


insert into PREMIUM_DB(Issue_State, Gross_Premium, Commissions, Premium_Tax, Carrier_Fee, Admin_Fee, 
Net_Premium, REPORT_DATE, FileRecdDate, Reference_Org, LoadDt
)

    select STATE, GROSSPREMIUM, COMMISSION, PREMIUMTAX, CARRIERFEE, ADMINISTRATOR, 
NETPREMIUM, REPORT_DATE, FILERECDDATE, $Reference_Org_Var, 
    
$Load_Date_Var

from EXCHANGE_BEN_PREM;
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE PREMIUM_DB

(Reference_Org varchar,
Gross_Premium number,
Commissions number,
TPA_Fee number,
Premium_Tax number,
Carrier_Fee number,
Admin_Fee number,
Net_Premium number,
Report_Date date,
LoadDt date,
FileRecdDate date,
);
```

Comment: How are these columns typed in the source and target tables?

Comment: Can you share the table definition? How did you define the Gross_Premium column?

Comment: They are all defined as "Number"

Comment: @JNevill The Source Table is loaded directly into snowflake using Matillion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the data type:

[NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#number)

> Precision  -  Total number of digits allowed.
>
> Scale -  **Number of digits allowed to the right of the decimal point.**
>
> By default, precision is 38 and **scale is 0** (i.e. NUMBER(38, 0))

---

I suggest changing: `Gross_Premium number` to `Gross_Premium number(38, 2)`.

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#data-types-for-fixed-point-numbers